# Recursively listing all files and directories over FTP: The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation

Tags: c#, exception, ftpwebrequest

I need to list all the files and folders (all files containing subfolders).

so I use console app to test.

Here is my source code..

*parameter count just for debug*

```
public static List<string> GetFile(string baseUrl, string username, string pwd, int count = 0)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    FtpWebRequest ftp = null;
    List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
    List<string> fileDetails = new List<string>();
    WebResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        ftp = CreateRequest(baseUrl, username, pwd, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory);
        response = ftp.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default))
        {

            string str = sr1.ReadLine();
            while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            {
                fileNames.Add(str);
                str = sr1.ReadLine();
            }
            response.Close();
        }

        ftp = CreateRequest(baseUrl, username, pwd, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails);
        using (response = ftp.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default))
        {

              ...
            }
        if (fileDetails.Count > 0 && fileNames.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var c in fileNames)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileDetails.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Contains(c) && d.StartsWith("d"))))
                {
                    //Directory
                    result.Add($"{baseUrl}/{c}");
                    result.AddRange(GetFile($"{baseUrl}/{c}", username, pwd, count += 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add($"{baseUrl}/{c}");
                }
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Add(count.ToString());
        result.Add(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
            response.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Some time I will get exception like this：

> System.Net.WebException: 'The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation.'

How can I solve this problem?
This exception not throw the same time

so maybe this problem from server side?

Comment: The Exception seems to be pretty clear. Still, have you tried your code with another FTP server?

Comment: I don't have another FTP server

Comment: I assume you're testing locally. Which FTP Server application are you using right now? You might want to install another FTP Server your machine and retry the connection.

Comment: FTP server is the official environment, I will build a Local Server and do another test.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the server. I set up an FTP server, which puts about 10,000 files and folders, but it can be executed normally.
Thank you for your help, I didn't think of this test method